# Is there a way I can retrieve the external base url of the Airflow Server via python?

Tags: python, airflow

I will want to provide a direct access to the log file. However, client will be accessing via external IP. So i will like to see if there's any way i can print out the external base url in order for my client to access directly to the log.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access shell via SSH, you can `curl` to IP checking website like `curl ifconfig.co`.

In Python, you can achieve the same thing with `requests` library.

```
import requests
res = requests.get("http://ifconfig.co/ip")
print(res.text.strip())
```

For Airflow, you can write the above script as a function and call it using `PythonOperator` to execute it.

However, if the Airflow is configured behind a web proxy, like nginx, it may prevent directly access via IP address from the forwarding rule.

Comment: Note: there are a lot of IP checking websites that you can use. I use ifconfig.co because of its memorable name.

Comment: Hi, Fony. I tried accessing with the ip but unable to connect to the web server.

Comment: That mean, you cannot access Airflow UI at all? It could be a firewall problem, are you sure that you has allow TCP 8080 (default Airflow port) ?

Comment: But for this question, it's asking about getting the IP, if you can run DAG on the Airflow, you can create a simple DAG and print the IP using the python code above, maybe save the result as a file or something you can access, as you cannot see the log.

Comment: Another possibility is that there is a proxy (e.g. nginx) as a front layer of Airflow that refuses to access via IP. In that case, it would be hard to find the right domain name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is because of this issue you mentioned where a proxy (e.g. nginx) as a front layer of Airflow that refuses to access via IP. Appreciate the help, makes it a lot easier to resolve.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if it helps you. So, it can be marked as answered. :-)

Comment: Update: I added more information about proxy in the answer.